# will a message be lost by a Aeron subscriber, if it still has not been received and the term has been rotated?

Tags: aeron

If the last message in a term is not received by a subscriber, but subsequent messages from the next term are received, would term rotation happen and the message be lost? Or are we fine as long as the message is received before the term to which it belongs is not cleaned up (garbaged collected)

I am assuming that the concept of 3 terms (Active/Dirty/Clean) apply both on the publisher and subscriber side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages are received in order so the situation you describe cannot happen. If loss occurs then flow control will hold back the sender until the loss is recovered.

Comment: Ok i may have misunderstood.. but i thought messages could arrive out of order due to network.. For example if messages 1, 2 and 3 are published,  messages 1 and 3 could arrive and get appended to the log buffer.. but there would be a gap where message 2 would fit.. the subscriber would consume just message 1.. message 3 would still be appended to the logbuffer but wont be made available to the subscriber until message 2 is received as well...

Are you saying in this scenario, flow control would be used to prevent messages 4,5 etc from being sent?

Comment: The full detail to how this works can be seen in the open source code. If you need to know this level of detail without reviewing the code then consultancy services are available.